# Why the time-out values are so small?

Tags: asynchronous, timeout, async-await

I'm not sure if this is a pure stackoverflow relevant question. It is related to general design practice. Since I cannot think of another relevant stack exchange site, posting it here.

In the general design practice of converting an async call to sync one, we use a time-out and wait for  the results. While, this may not exactly a good practice from the point of view of responsiveness, it definitely makes the implementation easier.

I have seen many such implementations and often noticed that the developers tend to give a very small time-out value. I can understand that the people may have the need of a responsive system in mind when they did this. But many of these applications I have seen are very data critical ones where the loss of data is very bad. So, it is always better to wait more and try to get as much data instead of timing out early and giving an error message to the user. Now, the situations where the server failing to give data or the client unable to reach server etc are rare. In those situations, I expect the a large time-out for such waits. After all, these time-outs don't mean that the wait will definitely last until the given time-out value; the timeout value is only an upper limit. So, I have always arguing for higher values here. But I see the use of low values in more and more places and now I'm getting confused if really there is something else in this practice that I don't understand.

So, my question is : Are there any arguments, other than the need for responsiveness to implement a very small time-out for waiting?

Comment: What exactly do you consider a very small timeout?

Comment: @svick : This depends on concrete scenarios. I was only interested to know the general trade-offs in deciding time-outs. What prevents people from using big time-outs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, the right decision depends on the real-life data.
The timeout should be proportional to the time it usually takes to complete an operation successfully.

Sending a UDP message for example could take between 1 - 50 milliseconds so a timeout of 100 milliseconds is more than reasonable however copying a file over the wire could take minutes or more so a 100 millisecond timeout is laughable.

There are pros and cons to both short and long timeouts so it's a tradeoff. Longer timeouts use more resources (tasks, threads, memory, etc.) for the same amount of work while short timeouts, as you mentioned, may result in loss of data.

In conclusion, you need to set a configurable timeout that sounds reasonable and then figure out  whether you timeout too many operations in production or the other way around and calibrate accordingly.